# How to uncomment inline script in DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

Say I have an inline script in my DOM that's been commented out:

```
<!-- <script type='text/javascript' id='my-script'>
  alert('Boo!');
</script> -->
```

I can successfully find said comment in the DOM, but if I

```
const script = comment.nodeValue;
comment.replaceWith(script);
```

The comment does indeed get replaced in the DOM; however, it gets replaced by a text node, not a script node.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const locator = document.getElementById('foo');
  let comment = locator.nextSibling;

  if ( 3 === comment.nodeType ) {
    comment = comment.nextSibling;
  }

  if ( 8 !== comment.nodeType ) {
    console.warn('Oops! That\'s not a comment!');
  } else {
    const script = comment.nodeValue;
    comment.replaceWith(script);
  }
}
```

```html
    <div id='foo'></div>
    <!-- <script type='text/javascript' id='my-script'>
      alert('Boo!');
    </script> -->
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

Is there a way to insert it as a script other than by regex parsing the comment.nodeValue and manually building up a script node?

Comment: I don't think the `<script>` would be of any use if added after the page loaded unless you do one of the following [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/807895/2813224). BTW the `type type='text/javascript'` on that `<script>` tag is 1. incorrect two identical attributes on the same tag and 2. `type='text/javascript'` on `<script>` is a default that no longer needs to be added.

Comment: Re: the script not executing, I can deal with that once I get it actually inserted as a script if necessary. Re: 1) that's a typo, fixed in edit. Re: 2) that's WordPress's doing in this case, but thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way you could do it without needing to resort to regex.

Basically you create a new script element and then set the new script element's attributes and innerHTML by creating a dummy script element (from the text in the comment) and reading off the attributes and innerHTML from the dummy.

Note: The reason I don't just insert `dummyScriptElem` is because that doesn't cause the script to run when inserted.

```js
const bodyElem = document.querySelector('body');
const commentElem = getAllComments(bodyElem)[0];
const scriptElemAsStr = commentElem.nodeValue;

const dummyScriptElem = createElementFromHTML(scriptElemAsStr);
//commentElem.replaceWith(dummyScriptElem); //this doesn't run the script when it's inserted so instead we create newScriptElem below and insert that instead

const newScriptElem = document.createElement('script');
//set newScriptElem's attributes and innerHTML to match script tag in commentElem
for (let attrName of dummyScriptElem.getAttributeNames()) {
  const attrValue = dummyScriptElem.getAttribute(attrName);
  newScriptElem.setAttribute(attrName, attrValue);
}
newScriptElem.innerHTML = dummyScriptElem.innerHTML;

commentElem.replaceWith(newScriptElem);

//util functions

function createElementFromHTML(htmlString) {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = htmlString.trim();
  return div.firstChild;
}

function getAllComments(rootElem) {
    const comments = [];
    const iterator = document.createNodeIterator(rootElem, NodeFilter.SHOW_COMMENT, () => NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT, false);
    let curNode;
    while (curNode = iterator.nextNode()) {
        comments.push(curNode);
    }
    return comments;
}
```

```html
<!-- <script type='text/javascript' id='my-script'>
  alert('Boo!');
</script> -->
```

Comment: Very cool. Actually, your createElementFromHTML trick seems to work without any of the dummy stuff. i.e., `commentElem.replaceWith(createElementFromHTML(commentElem.nodeValue))` seems to Just Work. Maybe either simplify your answer, or explain what problem the dummy stuff is solving for? I already upvoted, and will mark correct once updated.

Comment: Updated my answer. If we just insert the `dummyScriptElem` directly, it doesn't run when inserted into the html.